# velocity of a joint between two frames using kinect sdk

Tags: kinect, velocity, frames

I'm stack for along time in this problem and i will really appreciate if any one could help me in that.

I  asked many times in many forums, i've searched alot but no answer that really helped me.

i'm developping an application where i have to calculate the velocity of a joint of skeleton body using vs c# 2012 and kinect sdk 1.7

i have first to be sure of  the logic of things before asking this question so,

if I understood correctly, the delta_time i'm looking for to calculate velocity, is not the duration of one frame (1/30s) but it must be calculated from two instants: 
1- the instant when detecting and saving the "joint point" in the first frame 
2- the instant when detecting and saving the same "joint point" in the next frame

if it's not true, thank you for clarifying things.

starting from this hypothesis, i wrote a code to :

- detectiong a person
- tracking the spine joint ==> if it's is tracked then saving its coordinates into a list (I reduced the work for the moment on the Y axis to simplify)
- pick up the time when saving the coordinates
- increment the framecounter (initially equal to zero)
- if the frame counter is > 1  calculate velocity ( x2 - x1)/(T2 - T1) and save it

here is a piece of the code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
double msNow;
double msPast;
double diff;
TimeSpan currentTime;
TimeSpan lastTime = new TimeSpan(0);
List<double> Sylist = new List<double>();
private int framecounter = 0;

private void KinectSensorOnAllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs allFramesReadyEventArgs)
    {
Skeleton first = GetFirstSkeleton(allFramesReadyEventArgs);


        if (first == null) // if there is no skeleton
        {
            txtP.Text = "No person detected"; // (Idle mode)
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            txtP.Text = "A person is detected";
            skeletonDetected = true;

            /// look if the person is totally detected



                find_coordinates(first);

                 /*******************************
                 * time computing *
                 /*******************************/

                currentTime = stopWatch.Elapsed;
                msNow = currentTime.Seconds * 1000 + currentTime.Milliseconds;
                if (lastTime.Ticks != 0)
                {
                    msPast = lastTime.Seconds * 1000 + lastTime.Milliseconds;
                    diff = msNow - msPast;
                }
                lastTime = currentTime;



        }


        //framecounter++;
    }
void find_coordinates(Skeleton first)
{
        //*modification 07052014 *****/

    Joint Spine = first.Joints[JointType.Spine];
    if  (Spine.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
    {

        double Sy = Spine.Position.Y;
     /*******************************
      * time starting *
     /*******************************/
        stopWatch.Start();

        Sylist.Add(Sy);
        framecounter++;
       }

        else
            return;

        if (framecounter > 1)
        {

            double delta_Distance = Sylist[Sylist.Count] - Sylist[Sylist.Count - 1];


        }


}
```

to be honnest, i dont really know how ti use timespan and stopwatch in this context ( i mean when there are frames to process many times/s)

i will be thankfull for any help !

Comment: Do you have errors ? what really is your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

First:
The SkeletonFrame has a property called Timespamp that you can use. It's better to use that one than to create your own timesystem because the timestamp is directly generated by the Kinect.

Second:
Keep track of the previous Timestamp and location.
Then it's just a matter of calculation.

(CurrentLocation - PreviousLocation) = Distance difference

(CurrentTimestamp - PreviousTimestamp) = Time taken to travel the distance.

For example you would get 0.1 meter per 33 miliseconds.
So you can get the meters per seconds like this = (1 second / time taken to travel) * distance difference. In the example this is = (1000/33)*0.1 = 3.03 meter per second.